# How do i get what the name of the device im using with s.server="" ? SiteCatalyst?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am sending page name and page information to SiteCatalyst.
I need to send the name of the device the visitor is using.

Could someone help me out

```
    s.pageName="<?php the_title();?> (<?php the_ID(); ?>)"

    s.server=""

    s.channel="Mobilwebben"
```

My question is what variable do I need to send s.server"" with so i could get the device name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` Quote from PHP.net:

> > Contents of the User-Agent: header from the current request, if there is one. This is a string denoting the user agent being which is accessing the page. A typical example is: Mozilla/4.5 [en] (X11; U; Linux 2.2.9 i586). Among other things, you can use this value with get_browser() to tailor your page's output to the capabilities of the user agent.

You may also use this free function to read the user agent using PHP:

[Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/)

I hope this helps.